# How to install gem file via HTTP?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I understand it is possible to install local gem file via

```
gem install --local test.gem
```

What if my `.gem` file is accessible via http (e,g, http://example.com/test.gem), any method to install it directly without download and install?

Comment: using [**wget**](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use source switch:

```
gem install test -s http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Local means in your local machine.

If you use Bundler you can specify a local path, a Git repository or even another RubyGems repository, but never a specific HTTP URI. Here's the [Gemfile specification](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/gemfile.5.html).

However, if the Gem is available at one URI, I don't see any reason why you should now use a command to download it (for example using `curl` or `wget`) locally and then use `gem install --local`.